# Attached is the technical detail document of test.cls file

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Which one is better, I am sending one attached file to my manager.

> - Please find attached technical detail document of the test.cls file.
> - Attached is the technical detail document of test.cls file.

Comment: Either would be fine once you get rid of that unwanted ***of the / of*** (plus I don't much like the word ***file*** being there, but that may not be strictly "ungrammatical").

Comment: Do you mean the document IS 'test.cls'; or the document is ABOUT  'test.cls'.  The comment from @FumbleFingers assumes the former, whereas I'm assuming the latter. In the later case, certainly delete "file".

Comment: @TrevorD: Good point. But this is probably *way* too basic for ELU, and even on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) I'd vote to close as "proofreading".

Answer (score 1):

As a programmer I'm assuming that .CLS file is a source program in VB6 which is mostly jargon here. So I assume that you are sending a document which describes the .CLS file.

In that case, you have to say:

> Please find the attached technical detail document for the file `test.cls`.
>
> (or)
>
> Attached is the technical detail document for `test.cls`.

Or if the file is something else, and you are sending the `test.cls` file itself as an attachment to your manager, say the following:

> Please find the attached technical detail document `test.cls`.
>
> (or)
>
> Attached is the technical detail decument `test.cls`.

That is, remove the part `file` and then it should be fine.